# Failed to load ldlinux.c32

Tags: linux, tails

I have installed Linux Tails on my USB and I've been using it just fine until I upgraded it to new version. After I restarted my PC I got error:

```
SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD 20150820 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H.Peter Anvin Et Al
Failed to load ldlinux.c32
```

Can someone please help me to fix this, I have really important stuff there.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, don’t panic: Your data is still there. You can access the USB drive’s data from, say, an Ubuntu Live CD/USB. You might have to jump through some hoops regarding encryption though.

Comment: @DanielB yes, I figured that out, I was able to access persistent folder, but thank you for reply anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to load ldlinux.c32

Are you using an `ext*` filesystem for your boot partition?

64-bit file-systems [are not supported by `syslinux`](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Filesystem#ext).

---

If you are,  try `resize2fs -s` on your USB boot partition.

For example, if your USB device is `/dev/sdb`, do `resize2fs -s /dev/sdb1`.